# Automatically replace rfc-xxxx with link to tools.ietf.org in chat and comments

Tags: feature-request

As I often cite RFC, can we replace all the keywords matching:

```
(rfc\-.{4})                            -> $1
(rfc\-.{4})-(0-9\\.){1,32}             -> $1 $2 
rfc=7605
```

by a link to the ietf-URL:

```
https://tools.ietf.org/html/$1
https://tools.ietf.org/html/$1#section-$2
```

In comments and chat only?

Where

- The RFC must exists
- The URL opens in a new tab
- Edit to the comments does not edit the link's HTML.

Comment: @close-voter: this is a valid [feature-request], not a question asking for programming help.

Comment: While the usefulness is rather limited, any reason why you would limit this only for comments and chat?

Comment: I also always wanted automatic linking to MDN docs on JavaScript questions, both in comments and in answers. E.g. _“`HTMLCollection`, `Array#some`, `DOMTokenList`”_ would automatically turn into _“[`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [`DOMTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList)”_.

Comment: I think you want links going to e.g. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7605, so without the dash. It should be possible to implement this in a userscript. I actually started writing one, but ran into the "the RFC must exists [sic]" requirement; issues with CORS.

Comment: Why is the FR get downvoted? Did I something wrong?

Comment: @PeterRader: Voting on Meta is different. Downvotes on feature requests usually mean people disagree with the request.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of automatically replacing chat / comment contents, it'd be more semantically correct to implement a markdown extension:

```
[rfc:1234]
```

This could be usable in chat, Q/A and comments, without breaking existing content.

That said, the usefulness of this seems rather limited.

---

Another option is a short script:

```js
$("textarea").each((_, element)=>{
  let $textArea = $(element);
  let replaced = $textArea.val()
    .replace(/rfc-(\d{4})/, "[rfc-$1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/$1)")
  $textArea.val(replaced)
    .trigger("paste");    // Update the rendered output
});
```

I'm not sure what the other format looks like, but this is a start.

It replaces `rfc-1234` with `[rfc-1234](https://tools.ietf.org/html/1234)`

Comment: $ is not defined

Comment: @TinyGiant: Oh yea, shouldn't have been a snippet...

Comment: If the autor write `[rfc-1234](https://tools.ietf.org/html/1234)` your script makes a `[[rfc-1234](https://tools.ietf.org/html/1234)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/1234)` what might be limited helpfull :D

Comment: And that's ___exactly___ why we don't want automatic replacements.